# A TextView is squeezing out another when it expands instead of wrapping

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to make a chatview for an android app, but I have a problem with the chat bubble squeezing the message time until it completely collapses it, and then it wraps to the next row.
This is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/chat_levi"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Insert text here"
            android:textColor="@color/blueGray50"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom|left"
            android:text="18:30"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And an image to show you how it looks like:
[image]

And this is what it looks like when it wraps:
[image]

I also have another layout for the other user in the chat, and for him I've just changed all of the gravity lefts to rights, and swapped the places of some elements, as can be seen in the last image (its very similar code, so I've excluded it, but if someone asks for it, I will add it). For that one, I get the desired effect.

[image]

Is there some kind of a fix to get the first one to behave the same way as the mirrored one?

Comment: you can add the proprety "android:maxLines:'1'". This will allow your TextView to have only 1 line

Comment: That just makes it so that the TextView for the time doesn't wrap its text to the next line before it gets squeezed out.

Comment: Why don't you give the time a fixed width?

Comment: It still gets pushed off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution. Because the mirrored one works flawlessly, I ended up just mirroring the (`RelativeLayout` of the "mirrored" one) with `android:scaleX="-1"`, and afterwards I used `android:scaleX="-1"` on the `TextView` elements.

Here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
android:scaleX="-1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right|center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="right|center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom|right"
            android:scaleX="-1"
            android:text="18:30"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/chat_levi"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleX="-1"
            android:text="Insert text here"
            android:textColor="@color/blueGray50"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the end result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/chat_levi"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Insert texaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaat here"
                android:textColor="@color/blueGray50"

                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </FrameLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom|left"
            android:text="18:30"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

upd:**Fixed spacing in the end**

Comment: This doesn't work. The text still gets squeezed out, and I need the space at the end.

Comment: please check the updated code, I was missed with version of edited file.However, this is workaround and I'd suggest to use ConstraintLayout to avoid nested views.

Comment: With that code the spacer View at the end gets squeezed out.

Comment: I fixed the spacing in the end and removed redundant LinearLayout, please check again ;)

Comment: Time doesn't follow the content. Its stays fixed. I came up with a solution. I will be posting it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a million ways to skin this cat, but you are already using weights to do your linear layout, you could do something very similar for your textviews:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Insert ioadjfojdajidijfaseidfijoajsdifjasdijfijsadpfaosdjiofipasjdifapsjdfjasdjfasidjfasdjfoipjoijoij here"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom|left"
            android:text="18:30"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
```

You can mess with the weights to give more or less room to your timestamp.

EDIT******

The other way to skin this cat would then be to just put maxwidth on your xml

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:maxWidth="250dp"
            android:text="Insert ijpoijiopjiopjiopjiopsdjfaisdjfipajsdifajsdifaisdfaidspjfipajdf here"

            android:textSize="16sp" />
```

You will have to manage it for different layouts, though.

Comment: When I add a weight to the the TextView with the bubble, the bubble automatically extends to take up its weight. I want the bubble (background) to wrap around the text. I want the one with time to have a fixed size and to not get pushed off.

Comment: I know that its doable with maxwidth, but I'm loosing plenty of freedom there. The mirrored one works with nearly identical code, and its optimized for everything.